# Laravel get all database connection name

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have multiple database defined in my laravel installation inside `database.php` and I would like to loop all database and perform the same operation in everyone.
Something like this:

```php
foreach ($somethingunknown as $connection){
    DB::connection($connection)->table('users')->where('id','=',1)->delete();
}
```

What is the best way to get all database name? Maybe if possible something with wildcard support.

Comment: Likely a typo, but `->where('id,'=',1)` is a syntax error, should be `->where('id','=',1)` (missing a `'` after `id`)

Comment: @TimLewis That wasn't he point of the question, but nice catch. Edited.

Comment: @AlexandreDanault Haha yeah. I could have edited myself (as like I said, figured it was a typo), but I tend to let the asker do that just it case it is, in fact, an error in their code. Thanks for fixing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
config('database.connections')
```

returns an array of all your connections and their settings.